# How to get $scope.someStuff response values into variable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, json

This is my angular controller:

```
angular
    .module('hameedApp', [])
    .controller('hameedController', function($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;

        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        })
    });
```

This is my html from body tag:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone No</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.gsm}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var test = {{contacts}}
    console.log(test);
</script>
```

I want to get above `{{contacts}}`  full array json data in one variable called "test".

is it possible?

Comment: did you know `angularjs` as well ? did you use `angular.value` before? maybe your question missing try from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular concept is anything you put in `$scope` is not directly accessible in `non-angular` code. What you can do is, you can assign it to any global variable using `window` object like below.

```
angular
    .module('hameedApp', [])
    .controller('hameedController', function($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;
            window.contacts = response.data;
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        })
    });
```

Now you can access that `contacts` anywhere in `angular` as well as `non-angular` code.

**Edited**

As you want to get the `contacts` in `non-angular` code, you have to use `callback` mechanism to tell your `non-angular` code about updated value. See below

In you `<head>`, add a new `method` in `window` like this

```
<head>
  <script>
    ....
    ....
    window.updateContacts = function(contacts) {
      console.log(contacts);
    }
    ....
    ....
  </script>
</head>
```

Now you can use this `callback` from `angular` code, like below

```
angular
    .module('hameedApp', [])
    .controller('hameedController', function($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;
            window.updateContacts(response.data);
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        })
    });
```

Comment: You have to evaluate after you assign it.

Comment: I guess currently you are evaluating it on page load, but at page load it will be `undefined`. Wait for response to return and then check it,

Comment: I think he is stuck, post full code with html also, may be helpful

Comment: not working still, 
i did not see anything in console now

Comment: Check for console too